# Updating multiple membership plan expiration dates at once

Tags: python, database, django

I have model action in `RequestAdmin` like this:

```
def offer_plan(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    class MembershipForm(forms.Form):
        plan = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Plan.objects.all(), required=True,empty_label=None)
        _selected_action = forms.CharField(widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput)
        expires = forms.DateField(initial="click to select date")

    selected = request.POST.getlist(admin.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME)
    links = {}
    if request.POST.get('submit'):
        form = MembershipForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            plan = form.cleaned_data['plan']
            expires = form.cleaned_data['expires']
            for _id in selected:
                Request.objects.filter(id=_id).update(offered_membership_plan=plan,expires=expires)
                links[Request.objects.filter(id=_id).get().email] = 'www.xyz.com/plan/' + str(int(_id))
            return render_to_response("success.html", {'links': links,
                }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else:
        form = MembershipForm(initial={'_selected_action': selected})
    return render_to_response("offer.html", {'form': form,
        'selected_action': selected,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How can I improve the above code (I think it's always better not to run database calls in `for` loops) by removing database calls in loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set the same values on multiple rows.  The query you want should be `UPDATE Requests SET offered_membership_plan=…, expires=… WHERE id IN (…, …, …)`, and [a way to achieve that](//stackoverflow.com/a/5956422/1157100) would be:

```
Request.objects.filter(id__in=selected).update(
    offered_membership_plan=plan,
    expires=expires
)
```